# How to replace text with an image/icon when scaling to mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I am newbie to this and can't find many specific answers. I am looking for a way to change text labels into images when the viewport is scaled down to mobile sizes. I have additional issues because I am doing so with Leaflet, a java script library for Open Street Maps. They organize things a little different and I have to inject my styling.

Here is my live page with icons: https://leksplay.com/playgroundmap (still working on my SSL cert).

My full inline styles are at the bottom. I have a couple of  things going on here.

- I am styling the input directly because Leaflet inserts a *div* between *label* and *input* not allowing me to trigger animation on the *label* based on "checked" *input* states.
- I am injecting a class into my *labels* through javascript. Leaflet allows this, example:

```
var overlayMaps = {
       "All Playgrounds": dummy[0],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6162-6637-4663-b262-356661343562/IconsMedium_WC.png' alt='Restrooms'>": dummy[1],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6238-6432-4162-a161-333539326537/IconsMedium_Grill.png' alt='Public grills'>": dummy[2],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3939-3338-4237-b732-346131313435/IconsMedium_Access.png' alt='Accessible equipment'>": dummy[3],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3634-3833-4338-b834-626437613735/IconsMedium_Indoor.png' alt='Indoor area'>": dummy[4],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3331-3632-4239-a333-343137356133/IconsMedium_Full_Fen.png' alt='Fully fenced'>": dummy[5],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3339-3038-4032-a638-626137393039/IconsMedium_Partial_.png' alt='Partially fenced'>": dummy[6],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3336-3333-4137-a562-346663633031/IconsMedium_Horse.png' alt='Animals'>": dummy[7],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3332-6230-4731-a138-373630383130/IconsMedium_Water.png' alt='Pool or beach'>": dummy[8],
       "<img class='icons' src='https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3761-3935-4338-b861-336231626433/IconsMedium_Toddler.png' alt='Toddler Area'>": dummy[9]
  };
```

- I am also having some issues with my flex container on smaller screens because of margins I can't manage to fix. On mobile there is too much space on the left and right side causing the container to only have two columns when clearly there is space for 3 or 4. Example:
  [photo of current mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv1PJ.png)

I am sure there is a way, maybe with jQuery (which I dont know), to either fix the flex container on mobile or simply transition from text only on desktop to icons when on a smaller screen. Here is a live example of the text only version: https://leksplay.com/test-and
My end goal is to find a way that can display my control box (filters) on mobile without the browser creating an overflow scroll box or making the user scroll needlessly far to get to the actual map.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div id="new-parent">
    </div>
    </div>


<script>// Create the control and add it to the map;

var control = L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps,{collapsed:false});
control.addTo(map);

// Call the getContainer routine.
var htmlObject = control.getContainer();
// Get the desired parent node.
var a = document.getElementById('new-parent');

// Finally append that node to the new parent.
function setParent(el, newParent)
{
    newParent.appendChild(el);
}
setParent(htmlObject, a);


</script>


<style>
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
    color: #435757;
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #dac4cd);
    font: min(3vw, 16px) 'Montserrat';
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
label:first-of-type {
    border: 3px solid #689c93;
    margin: min(1vw,10px) 75%;
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: min(.5vw, 5px) min(3vw, 15px) min(.5vw, 5px) min(.5vw, 5px);
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    border-radius: 100px;

}

.flexcontainer {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.icons {
    width: 70px;
}

#new-parent {
    position: relative;
}

</style>



<style>
.leaflet-control-layers-selector {
     --primary: #679C92;
     --secondary: #E0E0E0;
     --duration: 0.5s;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
     -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
     outline: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     perspective: 240px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     width: min(3.5vw, 25px);
     height: min(3.5vw, 25px);
     background-size: 300% 300%;
     transition: transform 0.3s;
     transform: translate(0vw, 0vw);
     transform-origin: center center;
     animation: var(--name, unchecked) var(--duration) ease forwards;
}
.leaflet-control-layers-selector:before, .leaflet-control-layers-selector:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     height: var(--height, 13px);
     left: 3px;
     top: var(--top, 3px);
     background: var(--background, var(--primary));
     animation: var(--name-icon-b, var(--name-icon, unchecked-icon)) var(--duration) ease forwards;
}
.leaflet-control-layers-selector:before {
     clip-path: polygon(0 0%);
}

.leaflet-control-layers-selector:active {
     --scale: 0.95;
}
.leaflet-control-layers-selector:checked {
     --name: checked;
     --name-icon-b: checked-icon;
     --name-icon-a: unchecked-icon;
}
 @keyframes checked-icon {
     from {
         transform: translateZ(12px);
    }
     to {
         transform: translateX(16px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(12px);
    }
}
 @keyframes unchecked-icon {
     from {
         transform: translateX(-16px) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(12px);
    }
     to {
         transform: translateZ(12px);
    }
}
 @keyframes checked {
     from {
         background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, var(--primary) 0%, var(--primary) 25%, var(--secondary) 25.1%, var(--secondary) 100%);
         background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
     to {
         background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, var(--primary) 0%, var(--primary) 25%, var(--secondary) 25.1%, var(--secondary) 100%);
         background-position: 50% 50%;
    }
}
 @keyframes unchecked {
     from {
         background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, var(--secondary) 0%, var(--secondary) 25%, var(--primary) 25.1%, var(--primary) 100%);
         background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
     to {
         background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, var(--secondary) 0%, var(--secondary) 25%, var(--primary) 25.1%, var(--primary) 100%);
         background-position: 50% 50%;
    }
}
 html {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 * {
     box-sizing: inherit;
}
 *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: inherit;
}

</style>




<style>
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    }

.leaflet-control-layers {
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,00) !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.leaflet-control-layers-overlays {
    display: flex !important;
    position:unset;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: unset;
    align-items: center;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0px 12.5% 0px 12.5%;
    align: center;
}


</style>
```

Comment: Did you try @media queries?

Comment: Your leksplay.com website shows a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error.

Comment: @Rishabh I did but was not able to get it to work reliably to replace the text. I even tried sending an nbsp and using CSS to fill the rest and it wasn't working.

Comment: @Wezelkrozum still working on the cert with my registrar, it's a whole thing and they are pissing me off

Comment: Ok, could I know which text you are trying to replace when on mobile screen?

Comment: @RishabhdevTyagi CSS media queries is the way to go. But I think that the complete css overrides the display: none; that you define in the CSS media query. I suggest you use the Developer Tools Inspector to see which CSS rules override each other. That way you can get a better understanding of why some CSS properties are correct and other are not.

Comment: I agree with you @Wezelkrozum.I was thinking to apply the background image when the view is on mobile device.

Comment: @RishabhdevTyagi I have a working example with text at https://leksplay.com/test-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**Step 1**: hide the text when the browser size is less than 991px or in mobile screens which have size less than 991px;

**Step 2**: set a background image.

```css
@media all and (max-width:991px){

    
      
  #tst1{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6162-6637-4663-b262-356661343562/IconsMedium_WC.png');     
       transition:all 0.3s;  
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst2{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6238-6432-4162-a161-333539326537/IconsMedium_Grill.png');  
       transition:all 0.3s;       
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst3{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3939-3338-4237-b732-346131313435/IconsMedium_Access.png');
       transition:all 0.3s;         
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst4{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3634-3833-4338-b834-626437613735/IconsMedium_Indoor.png'); 
       transition:all 0.3s;        
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst5{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3331-3632-4239-a333-343137356133/IconsMedium_Full_Fen.png');     
       transition:all 0.3s;  
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst6{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3339-3038-4032-a638-626137393039/IconsMedium_Partial_.png');    
       transition:all 0.3s;     
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst7{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3336-3333-4137-a562-346663633031/IconsMedium_Horse.png');  
       transition:all 0.3s;       
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst8{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3332-6230-4731-a138-373630383130/IconsMedium_Water.png');   
       transition:all 0.3s;      
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }
  #tst9{
      background-image:url('https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3761-3935-4338-b861-336231626433/IconsMedium_Toddler.png'); 
       transition:all 0.3s;       
       color:transparent;
       background-size:50px 25px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:center;



  }

 }
```

```html
<span id="tst1">Restrooms</span>

<span id="tst2">Public grills</span>

<span id="tst3">Accessible equipment</span>

<span id="tst4">Indoor area</span>

<span id="tst5">Fully fenced</span>

<span id="tst6">Partially fenced</span>

<span id="tst7">Animals</span>

<span id="tst8">Pool or beach</span>

<span id="tst9">Toddler Area</span>
```

I have done little modification to your code to make things working.Please run it full screen and reduce the browser's size to see the changes.

Also, replace the areas of your code with this code and apply css.I have taken 991px as breakpoint, but you can take breakpoint of your choice.

Comment: It took some finess but this worked magically. I was formatting my media queries incorrectly. Thanks for tipping me into the world of media queries. I even got a chance to use some interesting selectors.